# Quex: Defining UTF8 Regular expressions for Identifiers

Tags: c++, utf-8, quex

I'm upgrading an Ecmascript engine that previously used 
`Quex 0.64.8` to `Quex 0.67.5`. I have the lexer up and
running and it seems it can only detect ANSI tokens now, 
and not UTF-8 tokens as before.

Essentially, what I do is to supply the `--codec utf8` flag while
running Quex and use the following code to identify identifiers:

```
PATTERN_IDSTART  [^0-9+\-<>*()\[\]?=&|~\\/\^%!{}\n\t\r"':;,. ]

PATTERN_IDPART  {PATTERN_IDSTART}|{PATTERN_DIGIT}

PATTERN_ID      {PATTERN_IDSTART}{PATTERN_IDPART}*
```

The idea is to rather than specifying all allowed tokens I define
which are not acceptable instead and exclude those. The new lexer
detects identifiers such as "test1" or "safari" just fine, but seems
to have problems with "日本語" and "Örjan". I am also only using utf-8
and don't use either ICU or Iconv.

It feels like maybe I have misunderstood something here. Any help
solving this problem would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

It might be useful to know I run Quex with the following arguments:

```
-i ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ecmascript.qx
--analyzer-class ecmascript_lexer
--foreign-token-id-file ${BISON_ECMASCRIPT_PARSER_OUTPUT_HEADER}
--token-id-prefix TOK_ 
--template-compression 
--codec utf8 //--encoding utf8 since Quex 0.67.5
--buffer-element-size 1 
--buffer-element-type char
--odir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated
--language c++
--warning-on-outrun
```

EDIT 2:

I failed to re-create a small example since the utf-8 parsing
worked in the example. Therefore I have created a standalone
version of the lexer part of my ecmascript engine instead,
with the hope that it would be easier to see what's going wrong.

It is no longer clear to me if my problem is actually related
to parsing utf8 tokens. Quite possibly something may be wrong 
in my .qx file instead... either way, here is the standalone version
of my ecmascript lexer.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(ecmascript CXX)

if(MSVC)
    add_definitions(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
endif()

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

set(QUEX_NAMES "quex")

if(CMAKE_HOST_WIN32)
    set(QUEX_NAMES "quex.bat" ${QUEX_NAMES})
else()
    set(QUEX_NAMES "quex-exe.py" ${QUEX_NAMES})
endif()

find_program(QUEX NAMES ${QUEX_NAMES} REQUIRED
             HINTS ENV QUEX_PATH DOC "Path to Quex's executable."
             NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

find_path(QUEX_INCLUDE_DIR quex/core.py REQUIRED
          HINTS ENV QUEX_PATH DOC "Path to Quex's include directory"
          NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated)

add_definitions(-DQUEX_OPTION_LINE_NUMBER_COUNTING  
                -DQUEX_OPTION_ASSERTS_DISABLED)


add_definitions(-DQUEX_SETTING_BUFFER_SIZE=1024) # Sätter bufferstorleken på lexern

set(ECMASCRIPT_LEXER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/ecmascript_lexer)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${ECMASCRIPT_LEXER} 
                          ${ECMASCRIPT_LEXER}.cpp
                          ${ECMASCRIPT_LEXER}-token 
                          ${ECMASCRIPT_LEXER}-configuration
                          ${ECMASCRIPT_LEXER}-token_ids
                          COMMAND ${QUEX} -i ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ecmascript.qx
                                      --analyzer-class ecmascript_lexer # Namnet på lexern
                                      --foreign-token-id-file ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ecmascript_yacc.hpp # token-id genereras av bison
                                      --token-id-prefix TOK_  # Custom prefix för tokens (se ecmascript.y för detaljer) 
                                      --template-compression  # Optimera lägesövergångar om möjligt 
                                      --encoding utf8         # Basera lexern på teckentabell UTF8
                                      --buffer-element-size 1 # Använd en datatyp som är 1 byte stor 
                                      --buffer-element-type uint8_t
                                      --odir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated  # Berätta var alla genererade filer ska ligga 
                                      --language c++
                     DEPENDS ecmascript.qx VERBATIM
                     COMMENT "Generating ecmascript lexer..."
                     MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ecmascript.qx) # Detta styr i vilken ordning Quex och Bison körs 

include_directories(${QUEX_INCLUDE_DIR} 
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated)

set(es_lexer ${ECMASCRIPT_LEXER} 
             ${ECMASCRIPT_LEXER}.cpp
             _main.cpp)

set(es_generated ${es_lexer} ecmascript_yacc.hpp)

add_executable(es_lexer ${es_generated})
```

**ecmascript.qx**

```
header {
    #include <quex/code_base/extra/accumulator/Accumulator>

    #include "ecmascript_yacc.hpp"
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cstdio>

    #define BACKSPACE           '\x08'
    #define TAB                 '\x09'
    #define NEWLINE             '\x0A'
    #define VERTICALTAB         '\x0B'
    #define FORMFEED            '\x0C'
    #define CARRIAGERETURN      '\x0D'
    #define DOUBLEQUOTE         '\x22'
    #define SINGLEQUOTE         '\x27'
    #define DOUBLEBACKSLASH     '\x5C'
    #define NULLTERM            '\x00'
}

footer {
    #include <quex/code_base/extra/accumulator/Accumulator.i>
}

define {
    PATTERN_NEWLINE [\n\r]

    PATTERN_DIGIT       [0-9]
    PATTERN_NOZDIGIT    [1-9]
    PATTERN_DECINTLIT   "0"|{PATTERN_NOZDIGIT}{PATTERN_DIGIT}*
    PATTERN_EXPIND      "e"|"E"
    PATTERN_SIGNEDINT   {PATTERN_DIGIT}+|"+"{PATTERN_DIGIT}+|"-"{PATTERN_DIGIT}+
    PATTERN_EXPPART     {PATTERN_EXPIND}{PATTERN_SIGNEDINT}

    PATTERN_DECNUMBER {PATTERN_DECINTLIT}"."{PATTERN_DIGIT}*{PATTERN_EXPPART}?|"."{PATTERN_DIGIT}+{PATTERN_EXPPART}?|{PATTERN_DECINTLIT}{PATTERN_EXPPART}?

    PATTERN_HEXDIGIT    [0-9a-fA-F]
    PATTERN_HEXNUMBER   "0x"{PATTERN_HEXDIGIT}+|"0X"{PATTERN_HEXDIGIT}+

    PATTERN_UNIESCSEQ   \\u{PATTERN_HEXDIGIT}{4}

    PATTERN_STRING      "\""(\\"\""|[^"])*"\""

    PATTERN_DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING_DELIMITER "\""

    PATTERN_SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING_DELIMITER "'"

    PATTERN_SINGLELINE_COMMENT "//"[^\n\r]*

    PATTERN_IDSTART  [^0-9+\-<>*()\[\]?=&|~\\/\^%!{}\n\t\r"':;,. ]

    PATTERN_IDPART  {PATTERN_IDSTART}|{PATTERN_DIGIT}

    PATTERN_ID      {PATTERN_IDSTART}{PATTERN_IDPART}*      
}

mode EOF : <inheritable: only>  {    
    on_end_of_stream {
        self_send(TOK_LINETERM);  

        self_send(TOK_TERMINATION);
    }
}

mode RestrictedProduction : EOF
                            <skip: [ \t]>
{
    {PATTERN_NEWLINE}{
        self_send(';');
        self << Program;
    }

    on_failure {
        self.undo();
        self << Program;
    }
}

mode StringHelper : EOF
                    <inheritable: only>
{
    on_entry {
        self_send(TOK_QUOTE);
    }

    on_exit { 
        if(self.accumulator.text.begin != self.accumulator.text.end)
            self_send(TOK_STRLITPART);

        self_accumulator_flush(TOK_QUOTE);
    }

    {PATTERN_NEWLINE} => '\n';

    "\\b" { self_accumulator_add_character(BACKSPACE); }

    "\\t" { self_accumulator_add_character(TAB); }



    "\\n" { self_accumulator_add_character(NEWLINE); }

    "\\v" { self_accumulator_add_character(VERTICALTAB); }

    "\\f" { self_accumulator_add_character(FORMFEED); }

    "\\r" { self_accumulator_add_character(CARRIAGERETURN); }

    "\\\"" { self_accumulator_add_character(DOUBLEQUOTE); }

    "\\'" { self_accumulator_add_character(SINGLEQUOTE); }

    "\\\\" { self_accumulator_add_character(DOUBLEBACKSLASH); } 

    "\\0" { self_accumulator_add_character(NULLTERM); }

    "\\x"{PATTERN_HEXDIGIT}{2}
    {
        {
            unsigned long ulResult = strtoul(reinterpret_cast<char*>(Lexeme+2),0,16);
            uint8_t *const pBuffer = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&ulResult);
            self_accumulator_add(pBuffer,pBuffer+2);            
        }
    }

    on_failure {
        self_accumulator_add(Lexeme, LexemeEnd); 
    }
}

mode SingleQuoteString : StringHelper
{
    {PATTERN_SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING_DELIMITER}
    { 
        // Om vi hittade slutet på strängen så växlar vi tillbaka till Program-läget
        self << Program; 
    }
}

mode DoubleQuoteString : StringHelper
{
    {PATTERN_DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING_DELIMITER}
    { 
        // Om vi hittade slutet på strängen så växlar vi tillbaka till Program-läget
        self << Program; 
    }
}

mode PrefixHelper : EOF
                    <skip: [ \t]>   // Ignorera whitespace
{
    on_entry {
        self.seek_backward(3);
    }

    {PATTERN_NEWLINE} 
    {
        if(self.iParaCount == 0)
            self_send(';'); 
    }

    "++"
    {
        self_send(TOK_PLUSPLUS);
        self << Program;
    }

    "--"
    {   
        self_send(TOK_MINUSMINUS);
        self << Program;
    }

    on_failure {
        (void)Lexeme;
    }
}

mode Operators : <inheritable: only>
{
    "||"        => TOK_OR;
    "&&"        => TOK_AND; 
    "++"        { self << PrefixHelper; }
    "--"        { self << PrefixHelper; } 
    "==="       => TOK_EQEQEQ; 
    "=="        => TOK_EQEQ; 
    "!=="       => TOK_NEQEQ; 
    "!="        => TOK_NEQ;  
    "*="        => TOK_MULTEQ; 
    "/="        => TOK_DIVEQ;
    "%="        => TOK_MODEQ; 
    "+="        => TOK_PLUSEQ; 
    "\-="       => TOK_MINUSEQ;
    ">>>="      => TOK_GTGTGTEQ;
    ">>>"       => TOK_GTGTGT;   
    "<<="       => TOK_LTLTEQ; 
    ">>="       => TOK_GTGTEQ;
    "<<"        => TOK_LTLT; 
    ">>"        => TOK_GTGT;
    "<="        => TOK_LTE; 
    ">="        => TOK_GTE;  
    "&="        => TOK_AMPEQ; 
    "^="        => TOK_CIRCEQ; 
    "|="        => TOK_PIPEEQ; 

    ['=']       => '='; 
    ['!']       => '!'; 
    ['(']       { self_send('('); ++self.iParaCount; }
    ['+']       => '+';
    ['\-']      => '-';
    ['*']       => '*';
    ['/']       => '/';
    ['%']       => '%';
    ['<']       => '<';
    ['>']       => '>'; 
    ['\[']      => '[';
    ['\]']      => ']';
    ['.']       => '.';
    [',']       => ',';
    ['?']       => '?';
    [':']       => ':';
    ['~']       => '~';
    ['&']       => '&';
    ['^']       => '^';
    ['|']       => '|';
    ['{']       => '{';
    [';']       => ';';
    [')']       { self_send(')'); --self.iParaCount; }
    ['}']       { self_send(TOK_LINETERM); self_send('}'); }
}

mode Keywords : <inheritable: only>
{
    function        => TOK_FUNCTION; 
    return          { self_send(TOK_RETURN); self << RestrictedProduction; } 
    var             => TOK_VAR; 
    null            => TOK_NULL; 
    true            => TOK_TRUE; 
    false           => TOK_FALSE; 
    instanceof      => TOK_INSTANCEOF; 
    in              => TOK_IN; 
    delete          => TOK_DELETE; 
    void            => TOK_VOID; 
    typeof          => TOK_TYPEOF; 
    this            => TOK_THIS; 
    if              => TOK_IF; 
    else            => TOK_ELSE; 
    with            => TOK_WITH; 
    throw           { self_send(TOK_THROW); self << RestrictedProduction; } 
    try             => TOK_TRY; 
    catch           => TOK_CATCH; 
    finally         => TOK_FINALLY; 
    for             => TOK_FOR; 
    break           { self_send(TOK_BREAK); self << RestrictedProduction; } 
    continue        { self_send(TOK_CONTINUE); self << RestrictedProduction; } 
    while           => TOK_WHILE; 
    do              => TOK_DO; 
    switch          => TOK_SWITCH; 
    case            => TOK_CASE; 
    default         => TOK_DEFAULT; 
    new             => TOK_NEW; 
    synchronized    => TOK_SYNCHRONIZED; 
}

mode Values :  <inheritable: only>
{
    {PATTERN_DECNUMBER} => TOK_DECLIT(Lexeme);

    {PATTERN_HEXNUMBER} => TOK_HEXINTLIT(Lexeme);

    {PATTERN_DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING_DELIMITER} { self << DoubleQuoteString; }

    {PATTERN_SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING_DELIMITER} { self << SingleQuoteString; }  
}

mode Identifiers : <inheritable: only>
{   
    {PATTERN_ID} => TOK_ID(Lexeme);
}

mode Program : Keywords,
               Identifiers,
               Values,
               Operators,
               EOF              
               <skip: [ \t]>
               <skip_range: "/*" "*/">
{
    {PATTERN_NEWLINE}
    {
        if(self.iParaCount == 0)
            self_send(TOK_LINETERM);
    }

    {PATTERN_SINGLELINE_COMMENT}
    {} 
}

body {

    void push_token(const unsigned int uiToken)
    {
        self.uiLastToken = self.uiCurrentToken;
        self.uiCurrentToken = uiToken;
    }

    bool use_auto_semi() const
    { return uiLastToken == TOK_LINETERM; }

    unsigned int uiLastToken,
                 uiCurrentToken;

    int iParaCount;

    quex::Token* pLastID;

    QUEX_NAME(Accumulator) accumulator;
}

constructor {
    self.uiLastToken = 0;
    self.uiCurrentToken = 0;
    self.iParaCount = 0;
    self.pLastID = 0;

    if(!QUEX_NAME(Accumulator_construct)(&me->accumulator, me)) {
        return false;
    }   
}

destructor {
    QUEX_NAME(Accumulator_destruct)(&me->accumulator);
}

start = Program;
```

**ecmascript_yacc.hpp**

```
   #ifndef YY_ECMASCRIPT_YY_C_USERS_PATRIKJ_WORK_GIT_ECMASCRIPT_BUILD_VC14_X64_GENERATED_ECMASCRIPT_YACC_HPP_INCLUDED
# define YY_ECMASCRIPT_YY_C_USERS_PATRIKJ_WORK_GIT_ECMASCRIPT_BUILD_VC14_X64_GENERATED_ECMASCRIPT_YACC_HPP_INCLUDED

/* Token type.  */
#ifndef YYTOKENTYPE
# define YYTOKENTYPE
  enum yytokentype
  {
    TOK_TERMINATION = 0,
    TOK_UNINITIALIZED = 1,
    TOK_ID = 258,
    TOK_NULL = 259,
    TOK_TRUE = 260,
    TOK_FALSE = 261,
    TOK_DECLIT = 262,
    TOK_HEXINTLIT = 263,
    TOK_OR = 264,
    TOK_AND = 265,
    TOK_PLUSPLUS = 266,
    TOK_MINUSMINUS = 267,
    TOK_EQEQ = 268,
    TOK_NEQ = 269,
    TOK_EQEQEQ = 270,
    TOK_NEQEQ = 271,
    TOK_LTE = 272,
    TOK_GTE = 273,
    TOK_INSTANCEOF = 274,
    TOK_IN = 275,
    TOK_STRLITPART = 276,
    TOK_QUOTE = 277,
    TOK_VOID = 278,
    TOK_TYPEOF = 279,
    TOK_DELETE = 280,
    TOK_THIS = 281,
    TOK_LTLT = 282,
    TOK_GTGT = 283,
    TOK_GTGTGT = 284,
    TOK_MULTEQ = 285,
    TOK_DIVEQ = 286,
    TOK_MODEQ = 287,
    TOK_PLUSEQ = 288,
    TOK_MINUSEQ = 289,
    TOK_LTLTEQ = 290,
    TOK_GTGTEQ = 291,
    TOK_GTGTGTEQ = 292,
    TOK_AMPEQ = 293,
    TOK_CIRCEQ = 294,
    TOK_PIPEEQ = 295,
    TOK_IF = 296,
    TOK_ELSE = 297,
    TOK_RETURN = 298,
    TOK_VAR = 299,
    TOK_WITH = 300,
    TOK_THROW = 301,
    TOK_TRY = 302,
    TOK_CATCH = 303,
    TOK_FINALLY = 304,
    TOK_FOR = 305,
    TOK_BREAK = 306,
    TOK_CONTINUE = 307,
    TOK_WHILE = 308,
    TOK_DO = 309,
    TOK_SWITCH = 310,
    TOK_CASE = 311,
    TOK_DEFAULT = 312,
    TOK_NEW = 313,
    TOK_FUNCTION = 314,
    TOK_SYNCHRONIZED = 315,
    TOK_LINETERM = 316
  };
#endif

/* Value type.  */
#if ! defined YYSTYPE && ! defined YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED
typedef int YYSTYPE;
# define YYSTYPE_IS_TRIVIAL 1
# define YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED 1
#endif

#endif /* !YY_ECMASCRIPT_YY_C_USERS_PATRIKJ_WORK_GIT_ECMASCRIPT_BUILD_VC14_X64_GENERATED_ECMASCRIPT_YACC_HPP_INCLUDED  */
```

**_main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "ecmascript_lexer"

/****************************************************************************************/
void print_token(quex::Token* token)
{
    std::cout << token->get_string() << std::endl;
}

/****************************************************************************************/
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    quex::Token*     token = 0;
    quex::ecmascript_lexer  qlex;

    quex::ecmascript_lexer *lexer = quex::ecmascript_lexer::from_file_name("id_test.js", 0);

    while(lexer->error_code == E_Error_None) 
    {
        get_token:

        lexer->receive(&token);

        if(!token)
            break;

        print_token(token);

        lexer->push_token(token->type_id());

        if(token->type_id() == TOK_LINETERM)
            goto get_token;

        if(token->type_id() == TOK_ID)
            lexer->pLastID = token;

        if(token->type_id() == TOK_TERMINATION)
            break;
    }

    delete lexer;
    return 0;
}
```

**id_test.js** // Used for testing the lexer

```
test1 = safari;
myFunc()

function t(){}

if(test1 < 23)
    return myFunc(45);

myFunc();

svenskaåäö();

var kalleö = 34;

var _us=kalleö;

_us = 678

日本語 = "Nihongo" // Japanska språkets namn 

$myCar = _us

var new1 = kalleö ? t(); 

"kalleÖ, _us and $myCar should be ignored here"

 الفصحى = "Arabiska"

/*
    var new1 = kalleÖ ? t(); 

    "kalleÖ, _us and $myCar should be ignored here"
*/

// var new1 = kalleÖ ? t(); 
대한민국 = 45; 
대한민국X45 = "Value of: 대한민국" + 대한민국; 

ärta="ärta + 2"

mix帝With대한민국 = "success?"; 

Örjan;

önes;
cake;

Россия; 
РоссияX;
РоссияX
XРоссия;
XРоссия;

始皇帝 = "The First emperor"
始皇帝x2 = "The First emperor, twice?"
```

Best regards,

Patrik J

Comment: I would title the question 'Quex: Defining UTF8 Regular expressions for Identifiers'.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with C++?

Comment: It generates a lexer coded in C++. I would much prefer to tag this
question as "Quex" rather than C++, but lack the privileges to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you rely on Unicode Properties, in particular
`ID_Start` and `ID_Continue`, such that your .qx file contains

```
define {
    ID_START    \P{ID_Start} 
    ID_CONTINUE \P{ID_Continue}
    ID          {ID_START}{ID_CONTINUE}*
}
```

Quex then samples the UCS database and you won't have to worry about
the particular code points.

Also, if you only want to support a subset, use `intersection` to 
cut out the desired UCS range, as in the following example:

```
...
    ID_START    [: intersection([\X900-\X970], \P{ID_Start}) :]
    ID_CONTINUE [: intersection([\X900-\X970], \P{ID_Continue}) :]
...
```

PS, your solution is not totally wrong. Given a file example.qx:

```
define {
    PATTERN_IDSTART  [^0-9+\-<>*()\[\]?=&|~\\/\^%!{}\n\t\r"':;,. ]
    PATTERN_IDPART  {PATTERN_IDSTART}|[0-9]
    PATTERN_ID      {PATTERN_IDSTART}{PATTERN_IDPART}*
}

token { ID; WS; }

mode X { 
    {PATTERN_ID} => QUEX_TKN_ID(Lexeme); 
    [ \n\t]      => QUEX_TKN_WS(Lexeme); 
}
```

And some user file 'example.c':

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "EasyLexer.h"

void
print_token(quex_Token* token_p)
{   
    const size_t    BufferSize = 1024;
    char            buffer[1024];
    printf("%s \n", QUEX_NAME_TOKEN(get_string)(token_p, buffer, BufferSize));
}

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    quex_Token*     token_p = NULL;
    quex_EasyLexer  qlex;

    quex_EasyLexer_from_file_name(&qlex, "example.txt", NULL);

    while( qlex.error_code == E_Error_None ) {
        quex_EasyLexer_receive(&qlex, &token_p);
        if( ! token_p ) break;

        print_token(token_p);
        if( token_p->_id == QUEX_TKN_TERMINATION ) break;
    }

    quex_EasyLexer_destruct(&qlex);
    return 0;
}
```

then executing on the command line:

```
> quex -i tmp.qx --encoding utf8 --language C -o EasyLexer
> gcc -I$QUEX_PATH example.c EasyLexer.c -o example
> ./example example.txt
```

delivers

```
ID 'Örjan' 
WS '\n' 
ID '日本語' 
WS '\n'
```

given that the file 'example.txt' is UTF-8 encoded and contains

```
Örjan
日本語
```

I do not know what to say else. Am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: Sure, I could use properties instead. But what's wrong with "my way"? could you elaborate? Any idea why it worked before but doesn't work now?

Comment: If I call the get_string function I get the output:
ID '<converters of .text to pretty char disabled>', maybe that's related to my problem?

Comment: This message can only happen, if you are using a version from the repository--not an official release. The lexeme-converter refactoring, anyway, has nothing to do with your problem. But may be, you are using '--bet char'? So, stick with '--bet uint8_t' if you are using UTF8.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and it seems to accept more characters now. But when the lexer encounters the first Chinese
tokens it simply fails with the error code "NoHandler_OnBadLexatom".
I understand that Quex encounters some kind of error, but I am surprised it does since I my PATTERN_ID should accept most tokens.

Comment: Bad lexatom notifies the occurrence of code elements which are not valid in the given encoding.

Comment: Could you, please, catch the bad lexatom and tell what is was? May be you have a terminating zero in your stream. That is, you passed a buffer length 1 too long.

Comment: How would I go about caching the bad lexatom? I tried the event
handerl on_bad_lexatom but I couldn't get it to trigger. Could you provide
a small example?

Comment: Earlier you said, that the error 'NoHandler_OnBadLexatom' has been detected. Then, 'on_bad_lexatom' should trigger. If you provide me with a minimalist example, I will look into it.

Comment: I'll try to post an example later today.

Comment: I have a lot of other things to do at work atm. Hopefully I'll be able to
have the example ready this afternoon or on monday.

Comment: While creating the example I found that the example actually works as intended. I'll have to investigate this further...

Comment: So, would you like to set the checkmark and close this question?

Comment: I would like to, but the issue is still unsolved. Please see my second 
edit post. It contains an example program now that demonstrates my
problem.

Comment: Could you please, make the example a bit more dense? I am glad to help, but I could be more efficient, if you cut out those things from your example which are irrelevant to the behavior that you experience.

Comment: I'm not sure which parts of the example cause the issue. But I will try to make the example smaller to get to the meat of the issue.